# Unable to build .NET Core application in github actions pipeline

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core

I have configured build action in GitHub actions but it's not working and throwing this error:

> MSP.csproj(323,3): error MSB4019: The imported project
> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.200\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration
> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.200\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I have 323 lines in the `.csproj` file:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

Github action for reference :

```yaml
name: .NET
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-2022
    steps:
    - name:  Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: ️ Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 8.x.x
    - name: ℹ️ dotnet info
      run: dotnet --info
    - name:  Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: ️ Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: ✅ Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
```

try to help I'm stuck on this error from long time.